# Prove that M is the orthocenter of a triangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

My steps have been to set a + b + c = Vector(OM) 
Which implies that a + b + c = M - O and if we take the vertex A of our triangle as our origin, then we can say that M = b + c. But how does this show that M is the orthocenter?

Comment: Hint: if $\mathbf{a}=\vec{OA}$ and so on, and $O+\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}=D$, then $BOAD$ is a rhombus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|\vec a | = |\vec b | = |\vec c |$, and orthocenter is the common point of the perpendiculars drawn from vertices to the opposite side. Let $\vec m = \vec a + \vec b +\vec c$, so $\vec{AM}. \vec{BC} = (\vec m -\vec a).(\vec c - \vec b)= (\vec c + \vec b).(\vec c - \vec b) = |\vec c|^2 - |\vec b|^2 = 0$. So $AM$ is perpendicular to $BC$. Similarly, $BM \perp AC, CM \perp AB$.